# Clojure logging not working on simple example

Tags: logging, clojure

I have used logging with Clojure in the past with no issues. Suddenly, on server that's been fine before, it's not working.

This is the simplest possible project with no extra dependencies and config:

`project.clj`

```
(defproject test "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.8.0"]
                 [org.clojure/tools.logging "0.3.1"]]
  :main ^:skip-aot test.core
  :target-path "target/%s")
```

`src/test/core.clj`

```
(ns test.core
  (:require [clojure.tools.logging :as log]))

(defn -main
  [& args]
  (log/info "Hello INFO logger!")
  (log/debug "Hello DEBUG logger!")
  (log/warn "Hello WARN logger!")
  (println "Hello, STDOUT!")
  (binding [*out* *err*]
    (println "Hello, STDERR!")))
```

When I run it:

```
$ lein run
Hello, STDOUT!
Hello, STDERR!
```

I could start adding extra logging config, but I'm confused that the minimal example no longer works.

```
$ java -version
openjdk version "9-internal"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 9-internal+0-2016-04-14-195246.buildd.src)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 9-internal+0-2016-04-14-195246.buildd.src, mixed mode)
```

Of course, it works on my development machine (1.8.0 on Mac OS) ...

Edit:

It looks like this us due to the configuration of `java.util.logging` (which is `clojure.tools.logging`'s last line of fallback) because an unconfigured `java.util.logging.Logger` also doesn't write to stdout, but does when there's a `ConsoleHandler`.

Still, I think this is a valid Clojure question as it concerns the default behaviour of `clojure.tools.logging`.

Comment: I noticed that you're using OpenJDK "9-internal".  Have you tried it with OpenJDK 8 or Oracle JVM 8?

Comment: It's perfectly fine to answer your own question. No need to edit it into the question so it looks like the question is unanswerd. questions with answers are more likely to attract the attention of people who come by later with the same problem.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have an answer! I still don't know why it's behaving differently between server and dev machine.

Comment: Is the same JVM for both dev machine and server ? In my machine your example wasn't showing debug, I had to use log4j. I'm using jdk8u111 on windows 10.

Comment: No, I realised after posting that I'm running 8 in development an 9 on that server. I've switched back to version 8. In any case, I think the choice of log level is different to not sending *anything* to stdout. I'll need to re-check with Java 8.